# single popup window of only certain array values. javascript

Tags: javascript, function, loops, alert

Hi im trying to make a single popup window consisting of only values in the array that are larger/ smaller than a certain number. How can I go about doing this?

```
<script>
var moe = [3,3.14,4.3,8,9,19,23,24,46,54,87];
var noe = moe.indexOf(23);

function myFunction()
{
alert(noe);
}
function compare(){
for (var i=0;i<moe.length;i++){
if (moe[i]>10){
alert(moe[i]); 
}
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
function compare(){
    var out = [];
    for (var i=0;i<moe.length;i++){
        if (moe[i]>10){
            out.push(moe[i]);
        }
    }
    alert(out.join()); 
}
```

Comment: Use `out.join()` and dont make out a global

Answer (score 0):

Lets walk through the problem:

1. Given an array of values: `values = [3,3.14,4.3,8,9,19,23,24,46,54,87];`.
2. We want to *filter* the result based on the value being larger than 10.
3. Finally output the result in an alert dialog box (which takes a string).

Step one is to work out the filtering and then how to turn the result into a string to apps to the `alert()` function.

```
(function() {

  var i, len, values, value, results, string_value;

  values  = [3,3.14,4.3,8,9,19,23,24,46,54,87];
  results = []; // Empty array which we will build in order during the filter

  for (i = 0, len = values.length; i < len; i++) {
    value = values[i]; // Not needed; used for readability
    if (value > 10) {
      results.push(value); // Add this value to the results array
    }
  }

  // Now that we have a result lets convert that to a string
  string_value = results.join(", ");

  // And output the result with some string concatenation
  alert("Filtered results: [ " + string_value + " ]");

  // The use of string_value is optional, you could in-line
  // this into the alert line

})();
```